# how can i go back to the beginning when there is no next()

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i  go back to the beginning when there is no next()

```
$(function () {
  (function hideHeading() {
    setInterval(function () {
      $('.active').fadeOut(2000, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active').next().addClass('active').fadeIn(2000);
      });
    }, 2000);
  })();
});
```

example here

http://codepen.io/OsamaElzero/pen/LVeLeY

Comment: Repeat how? go back to the beginning when there is no next()?

Comment: yes ,go back to the beginning when there is no next()

Comment: So check if next() returns anything, if not select the first sibling

Comment: please send me code or example because i am beginner in Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need setInterval since you could simply do a recursion as below. If the `.next()` isn't there, set the pointer to `first()`.

```
$(function () {
    (function hideHeading() {
        $(".active").fadeOut(2000, function () {
            var $this = $(this).removeClass('active');
            var $next = ($this.next().length && $this.next()) || ($this.siblings().first());
            $next.addClass('active').fadeIn(2000, hideHeading);
        });
    }());
});
```

**[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waprrB)**

Comment: Very Good ^_^ , Thanks

Comment: Play with the duration, change 2000 to 5000.

Answer (score 0):

Check if next is an element, if not, select the first sibling.

```
var elem = $(this).removeClass('active')
var next = elem.next();
if(next.length===0) {
    next = elem.siblings().first();
}
next.addClass('active').fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: Simple typo, wish you put in the effort to debug it.... Remeber we are here helping you for free so ease up.